# Mock returns null value when ReturnResult is a custom object but works as expected when it is a primitive type bool

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, .net-core, moq

I am using Moq in .net core(1.1) and having a bit of torrid time understanding this behavior as all the examples on interweb points to the fact the this should work with no issues.

I have already tried with:

- Returns(Task.FromResult(...)
- Returns(Task.FromResult(...)
- ReturnsAsync(...)

Mocking a `IHttpClien`t interface to wrap `PostAsync`, `PutAsync` and `GetAsync`. All of these return an `ApiResponse` object.

```
var mockClient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
```

**Does  not work**:

```
mockClient.Setup(x => x.PostAsync(url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), null))
                                    .Returns(Task.FromResult(new ApiResponse()));
```

***PostSync definition***:

```
public async Task<ApiResponse> PostAsync(string url, string body, string authToken = null)
```

**Does work**:

```
mockClient.Setup(x => x.PostAsync(url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), null))
                                     .Returns(Task.FromResult(bool));
```

***PostSync definition***:

```
public async Task<bool> PostAsync(string url, string body, string authToken = null)
```

Usage:

```
var api = new ApiService(mockClient.Object);
var response = api.LoginAsync(body.Username, body.Password);
```

**UPDATE**

```
[Fact]
public async void TestLogin()
{
   var mockClient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
   mockClient.Setup(x => x.PostAsync(url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), null)).Returns(Task.FromResult(new ApiResponse()));

   var api = new ApiService(mockClient.Object);
   var response = await api.LoginAsync(body.Username, body.Password);
   Assert.IsTrue(response);
}
```

Return Type:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
     public string Content { get; set; }

     public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }

     public string Reason { get; set; }
}
```

LoginAsync:

```
public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string user, string password)
{
    var body = new { Username = user, Password = password };
    try
    {
        var response = await _http.PostAsync(_login_url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), null);
        return response .State == 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex);
        return false;
    }
 }
```

PostAsync:

```
public async Task<object> PostAsync(string url, string body, string authToken = null)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
    var resp = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return new ApiResponse
    {
        Content = resp,
        StatusCode = response.Result.StatusCode,
        Reason = response.Result.ReasonPhrase
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a simple method under test like this based on minimal example provided above.

```
public class ApiService {
    private IHttpClient _http;
    private string _login_url;

    public ApiService(IHttpClient httpClient) {
        this._http = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string user, string password) {
        var body = new { Username = user, Password = password };
        try {
            var response = await _http.PostAsync(_login_url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), null);
            return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Logger.Error(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The following test works when configured correctly

```
[Fact]
public async Task Login_Should_Return_True() { //<-- note the Task and not void
    //Arrange
    var mockClient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
    mockClient
        .Setup(x => x.PostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), null))
        .ReturnsAsync(new ApiResponse() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK });

    var api = new ApiService(mockClient.Object);

    //Act
    var response = await api.LoginAsync("", "");

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(response);
}
```

The above is just for demonstrative purposes only to show that it can work provided the test is configured properly and exercised based on the expected behavior.

Take some time and review the [Moq quick start](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the framework.

Comment: Agreed. As far as I can tell, the key difference seems to be in setup where I inferred the param types vs your "correct" setup. I guess assumptions can really make an ass. Though would love to dig deeper into why what I used was "incorrect". **Much appreciated!**

Comment: @Walaitki moq responds directly to what you configure to expect. Though my example was very simple, you need to setup the moq to expect the behavior you want to test. If you do not provide the behavior the mock expects then it wont perform as expected. To say exactly why yours did not work, there is not enough details in the question. too many missing pieces to the puzzle. could something as simple and a misplaced space in a string.

Comment: `It.IsAny` quite a dangerous **demonstrative** example, you know :)

Comment: @VMAtm how so? depending on the nature of the test you sometimes do not care about the dependencies. You just want to make sure they do not cause errors that can hinder the exercising of the test. Remember these types of unit tests are meant to be done in isolation. :)

Comment: The main problem with that code is it's easy to copy it and paste to the tests which are really should care about the arguments. For me, in this case it's better to setup a pair `user/password`, and do the setup according to their values.